# FLENS/promotion.h, syntax error?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, g++

I want to compile [FLENS](http://apfel.mathematik.uni-ulm.de/~lehn/flens/) using VC++ 11.0. However I've encountered an unusual syntax error. What does ``**typename...**'' mean?

```
template <typename... Args>
struct Promotion
{
};
```

Is this normal in g++ ?

Please take a look at 
http://www.mathematik.uni-ulm.de/~lehn/FLENS/flens/auxiliary/promotion.h.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is C++11 [variadic templates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_template). You would need Visual Studio 2013 to compile this code according to [this table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh567368.aspx).

Comment: Thank you for your elaboration.

Answer (score 0):

It's C++11 standard. Variadic templates.